# How to solve '''-XX:ParallelGCThreads=N''' error?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm use elasticsearch-2.4.1 and openjdk version 1.8.0_265.

When I start elasticsearch, I meet the error message.

[image]

I found the solution web site. But I didn't solve yet.

`https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22245`

Curently, I add a `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=N` in `elasticsearch-2.4.1/config/jvm.options`

How can I solve this problem? Please give me correct answer. Thank you sir. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html)

> On a machine with N hardware threads where N is greater than 8, the
> parallel collector uses a fixed fraction of N as the number of garbage
> collector threads. The fraction is approximately 5/8 for large values
> of N. At values of N below 8, the number used is N.

So there are two cases:

- if you have 8 CPUs or less => set N = number of CPUs
- if you have more than 8 CPUs => set N = 5/8 * number of CPUs

Comment: 1+, just notice that by default it is `10`, for a machine with less then 8 cores (which is the majority I have seen with elastic), this is a bad set-up, which contributes to the "elastic is slow" argument that I have heard numerous times. And while the recommendation tries to "fit all cases", it does not. This heavily depends on the set-up you have, the garbage collector underneath  and what the statistics show you from GC logs.

Comment: I agree with you @Eugene. It is also worth noting that 2.4.1 is a pretty ancient version of ES in which those JVM settings were probably less optimized than they are in more recent versions

Comment: @Eugene I haven't tagged anyone, just trying to get the OP to give some feedback and since he's the OP, no need to tag him

Answer (score 0):

`-XX:ParallelGCThreads=N` here `N` is the variable and you need to give some value to it according to your machine size(number of processors), like `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4` for example.

Please refer @Val answer for Java recommendation on how to set the best value according to your environment.

Comment: ... and you say `4` because?

Comment: @Eugene, I mentioned some value according to machine size, `like` its example number which I gave to make it clear

Comment: sorry, but that's like saying nothing. you could have said set it to `10_000`, with the same success.

Comment: @Eugene, thanks for the suggestion, if you were at my place and you have to give general recommendations.  how would you phrase it?? I know I didn't provide the specific example what Val added in his answer, but my answer was sort of general advise to quickly fix the error OP is facing, I could have found the specific value but I left that to OP :)

Comment: if I had to answer that I would explicitly explain, at least at a high level, what parameter does. and the mere fact that you say "I could have found the specific value" pretty much sums up the fact that you might not be aware of _exactly_ what it does or may be you are, but if so, you need to understand that this value is only correctly set empirically. It can' be computed solely based on "machine size", whatever that means.

Comment: @Eugene thanks for your feedback, will update the answer and keep this advise in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

-XX:ParallelGCThreads=N, here N can be maximum to the number of cpu cores your machine has. This argument means that N parallel GC threads will run to clean up the heap space.